# Flutter Pixels Overflow to the Right With BottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter

I am using a BottomNavigationBar and trying to add notification number next to the bar item icon (Like facebook for instance). I came up with the below and it is working fine on mobiles, however while testing on Tablet, it generated "Pixels Overflow to the right", don't understand why. the problem coming from the SizedBox Width I am giving to the icon Widget, it is generating 24 pixels overflow for the 30 width I am giving.

any idea why and how to solve it?

```
  BottomNavyBar(
                selectedIndex: _currentIndex,
                backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 248, 244, 246),
                containerHeight: 50.h,
                onItemSelected: (index) {
                  setState(() {
                               _currentIndex = index;
                               _pageController.jumpToPage(index);
                               });
                                  },
                items: <BottomNavyBarItem>[
                           BottomNavyBarItem()
                           BottomNavyBarItem(
                            title: Text('Reviews'.tr),
                            icon: SizedBox(
                                    width: 30.w, //Here is the part where the problem is
                                    height: 30.h,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        activeColor: const Color.fromARGB(
                                            255, 245, 91, 165),
                                        inactiveColor: Colors.grey[850]),

                                  ],
                                ),
```

Comment: My answer is not associated with your question but at least you should write your code readable to ask someone.

Comment: What is unreadable in the question?  do you mean the format?

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using the BottomNavyBar package.

They're example for a BottomNavyBarItem is:

```
     BottomNavyBarItem(
     icon: Icon(Icons.people),
     title: Text('Users'),
     activeColor: Colors.purpleAccent
```

You're introducing a minWidth constraint that probably conflicts.  You'll need to get rid of the sized box, not use the package or ask/pr a feature request.

Comment: I removed the stack and the problem is still exist, it is coming from the sized box width, for instance if I reduced the width to 10 the overflow is no longer exists. noting that this issue happens only with tablets, on mobile it has no issue at all

Comment: Changed my answer to above.  In that package, it would seem they designed it to not allow that kind of width.